Can we get benefits of Chandipath by chanting only the 4th chapter?
The 4th chapter of Chandipath describes the gunas of the Devi. So can we chant the 4th chapter only to get rid of the bad effects of our bad karmas and earn punyas in our lives ? Also is there any particular method where we can get the benefits of Chandi path in a simpler rituals and practice without much rules and regulation?

Seems like you need initiation for chandipath. So guru can guide.
